# Ruby on Rails Ckeditor tags shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I've got an issue with ckeditor. after text posted/page created in preview it shows tags. 
How I can fix it and see only edited text itself?

[image: screnshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your view try

```
 <%= raw(@yourvariable) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I my application I use Rails .html_safe method for that purpose.

```
<%= string_from_ckeditor.html_safe %>
```